# Is it possible to do the Kattis "Mixed Fractions Q" in C and under the 2 second limit

Tags: c, fractions

Basically i've attempted to answer this question from Kattis:
https://open.kattis.com/problems/mixedfractions

I have a working solution however it goes over the allocated 2 second time limit for computation.  My question is essentially, is it even possible to write a solution to this problem in the C programming language that can compute the maximum input in under 2 seconds.

When reading through the other statistics "problems/mixedfractions/statistics" I've noticed that nobody else has used C or similar procedural languages.  The feedback just says it went over the time limit but I'm not sure if that's because C can't do the calculation fast enough or if I've made a mistake in my code.

Thanks for the help, I'll chuck my code in below for reference!

http://pastebin.com/7EtA2d3S

EDIT: Thanks for the response to the question, as you can see I'm new to the SO scene and to C (well programming in general) and was just trying to practice, sorry if my code was dreadful.  Basically to clarify all I was trying to ask was if this particular question is possible in C (because nobody else had done it in C), thanks again and I'll try and get this post removed so not to waste anyone else's time.

Comment: Both your links are broken

Comment: Your question is certainly too vague. On SO, we'd expect you give a concise overview of your problem yourself. Don't refer to your code as links. The case being your code is just bad. Have a look into how division `/` and remainder `%` operators work in C. You are replacing multiplicative arithmetic by additions, which is ridiculous. Voting to close.

Comment: (porting answer to comment): Your question is kind of limited -- having read the "mixed fractions" problem I feel confident in saying that yes, a program in C could be written to calculate the answer for any value in the problem domain in less than 2 seconds.

As Jens' comment indicates, your algorithm is the problem here. A divide-and-modulo approach will be much faster.

Comment: If it's just the three test cases presented in the files, frankly I'd be surprised if it took more than 2 _microseconds_!

Comment: It also depends somewhat on what hardware you're running it on:)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I hope you were not offended by the response you got. It's because your question comes off as arrogant (blaming C or Kattis for problems with your code), although I'm not sure that's what you intended. It's difficult to find a language that gives you better performance than C, and in particular it performs better than any other language that Kattis allows. But please remember that C doesn't make your code fast! It won't save you from making bad design decisions. Read up on algorithms, datastructures and computational complexity theory to learn how to make your C code efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine how your code remotely managed to exceed 2s runtime on the three samples given.

The version I just knocked up runs so fast it doesn't register any time at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        unsigned int        a, b;
        unsigned int        c, d, e;

        scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);
        if (a == 0 && b == 0) break;

        c = a / b;
        d = a % b;
        e = b;

        printf("%u %u / %u\n", c, d, e);
    }
}
```

Running:

```
% /usr/bin/time ./mixed < data.in > data.out
    0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
```

**EDIT** Ah, I see - Kattis has its own runtime environment, and supplies larger data sets than the sample shown on the page.  My time on Kattis itself was 0.04s - not fantastic, but not horrendous either.  Using the `div(n, d)` function that calculates the remainder and quotient in one step is faster.